# MacBook Pro -> (HDMI) -> Samsung SP-400DS projector fails

Tags: hdmi, projector

The listed combination seems to fail (i.e. the OS X 10.6 "Detect Displays" button doesn't seem to detect the projector as an additional display). Is there any reason why this should be so, or tips to help troubleshoot the problem?

Edit: turns out it doesn't work with the 15m HDMI cable we bought with it, and it works fine with a shorter (2m) cable we had in supply.

Comment: Since no Mac ever shipped has an HDMI port, what is your adapter? Is it DVI > HDMI or Mini DisplayPort > HDMI? What brand?

Comment: It's MiniDisplayPort > HDMI, non-Apple (some orange package, APR, I think?).

Comment: You should put your edit as an answer, as it seems to have solved the problem (the cable was too long for your adapter to handle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up failing with the 15m HDMI cable we used. The long cable worked when using it from another computer with the same beamer, but with the laptop it only ended up working with a shorter cable.

Comment: This happens to me always. HDMI, USB, LAN ... every kind of cable. (One should always use the shortest possible.)